# SQL Count with IF-ELSE

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a SQL command that in person table device history is stored per person. current device is not null devicex_mac. So there is possible that device2_mac could be current device (device3_mac is null) or device1_max could be current device(device2_mac and device3_mac are both null).

```
**Person Table**            
id  device1_mac device2_mac device3_mac


**Device Table**        
mac   brand   model
```

With the fact above how may I detect current device and JOIN both tables in order to get the following result.

```
**RESULT:**

BRAND   MODEL   COUNT
BRAND1  Model1  350000
BRAND1  Model2  700000
BRAND2  Model1  480000
```

Comment: So only one column can be non null and you want to join on that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wanted to see the distribution of all the columns, you would do:

```
select d.brand, d.model, count(*)
from ((select id, device1_mac as mac
       from person
      ) union all
      (select id, device2_mac
       from person
      ) union all
      (select id, device3_mac
       from person
      )
     ) pd left outer join
     devices d
     on pd.mac = d.mac
where mac is not null
group by d.brand, d.model
```

If the last column contains the information you want, you would do:

```
select d.brand, d.model, count(*)
from person p left outer join
     devices d
     on coalesce(p.device3_mac, p.device2_mac, p.device1_mac) = d.mac
where mac is not null
group by d.brand, d.model
```

`coalesce()` chooses the first non-NULL value.

EDIT:

If the question is about performance *and* there is an index on `devices(mac)`, then I would suggest a variation on the first query:

```
select d.brand, d.model, count(*)
from ((select id, device1_mac as mac
       from person
       where device2_mac is null and device1_mac is not null
      ) union all
      (select id, device2_mac
       from person
       where device3_mac is null and device2_mac is not null
      ) union all
      (select id, device3_mac
       from person
       where device3_mac is not null
      )
     ) pd left outer join
     devices d
     on pd.mac = d.mac
where mac is not null
group by d.brand, d.model
```

The use of functions or `or` in an `on` clause often cause databases to ignore indexes.

Comment: Wont `coalesce` force an index scan of the table?

Comment: @Magnus . . . The original question does not provide the layout of the tables, mention performance, or even mention the database.  Under such circumstances, I don't "read" performance into the question.  By the way, the use of `or` in an `on` clause can have just as bad an effect on performance as `coalesce()`, in some databases.

Comment: Wast just an observation. By the way I have never noticed that an `or` in the join would force an index scan in the databases I've worked with (Sql Server, Oracle)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that only one of the device columns has a value at any time. Then you can do:

```
SELECT
   brand,
   model,
   COUNT(*)
FROM
  tblDevice 
  JOIN tblPerson ON
     tblDevice.mac = tblPerson.device1_mac OR
     tblDevice.mac = tblPerson.device2_mac OR
     tblDevice.mac = tblPerson.device3_mac
group by 
   brand, 
   model
```

Comment: since current device is not null last device, can we change the order tblDevice.mac = tblPerson.device3_mac OR
     tblDevice.mac = tblPerson.device2_mac OR
     tblDevice.mac = tblPerson.device1_mac
?

Comment: and I want to count the number of person, in that case JOIN could be ON DEVICE table?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but you can always change it to a right join.

Comment: I mean , does this query quarenty that device->mac matching with not null last devicex_mac in Person table?

Comment: This query will only work if only one of the columns have a non null value and the other are null. Is that not the case?

Comment: Assume that device1_mac=11111, device2_mac=222222, device3_mac=null, in that case device2_mac should be matched by mac of Device Table. In other words current device is device2_mac and others will be ignored while sql execution.

Comment: Ok, I see. Than I think you need to go with @Gordon Linoff's suggestion on this.